# how to know a pop up is opened in current window in jquery?

Tags: jquery

i have seen [here](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-check-if-a-popup-is-open)
its related to mobile popup. i want to find for jquery-1.8.3.min. in my situation i have one pop up opened after 8 secs of page visit and some use cases there users will click an image or an video in my page and they will continue to watch it, what happens here when that 8 secs got over the 8 sec pop will be showing up on the video or image i am watching. i have to hide or not to show that 8 sec pop when other one is opened.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class active to the active popup and then check if the popup has the class active or not.

checking if a item has a class is easy in Jquery

```
$('#popupName').hasClass('active');
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: That'll work too. You might need to do an each statement for this example.

$( ".popupWindow" ).each(function() {
  // do stuff
});

Answer (score 0):

You can verify if the class is present or check if the popup is visible.

```
$(element).is(":visible") 
// or 
$(element).hasClass('classPresentWhenPopupOpened');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quick and dirty method.

```
<div id="dialog1">My video in here</div>
<button class="openDialog" data-dialog="dialog1">OPEN</button>
<script>
```

```
        $(function() {


            $( "#dialog1" ).dialog();

            $( ".openDialog" ).click(function() {

                var dialogId = $(this).attr('data-dialog');

                if ( !$(body).hasClass("dialogOpen") ) {

                    var openWindow = $(body).attr("data-openDialog"); // get id of previously opened window
                    $('#'+openWindow).dialog('close');                              // close dialog
                    $(body).attr("data-openDialog", "");                            // clear data
                    $(body).removeClass("dialogOpen");                              // remove class

                } else {

                    $(body).attr("data-openDialog", dialogId);  // add data to indicate dialog is open
                    $('#'+dialogId).dialog('open');                         // open dialog
                    $(body).addClass("dialogOpen");                         // add class to indicate dialog is open

                }

            });

        });
```

```
</script>
```